# Simple propositional logic proposition goes back and forth when extending

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose the proposition A OR (A AND B).The value of that proposition turns out to be A.Shouldn't (<=>) extension lead to ... <=> A ?This is not the case,it just simply leads back to: 
... <=> A AND (A OR B).My question is why is this happening?Shouldn't math do the work and conclude that the original proposition eventually leads to A alone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
A&B&A\vee(A\wedge B)&A\wedge(A\vee B) \\
\hline
0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0 \\
1&0&1&1 \\
1&1&1&1
\end{array}
$$

As you can see, the columns for $A$, $A\vee(A\wedge B)$ and $A\wedge(A\vee B)$ have the same logic values, so we can say, that
$$
A\vee(A\wedge B) \Leftrightarrow A \Leftrightarrow A\wedge(A\vee B)
$$

Therefore math did the work by concluding $A\wedge(A\vee B)$.

**Edit**

This is one way of concluding $A$.

To show, that $A \Rightarrow A\vee(A\wedge B)$ we will just use simple law, that $A \Rightarrow A \vee C$ for any $C$, in this case $C\equiv A \wedge B$. It's pretty obvius, how to use it in this case, isn't it?

To show the other way implication first of all we will expand the alternative:

$$A\vee (A\wedge B) \Rightarrow (A \vee A) \wedge (A\vee B)$$
Of course $A\vee A \Rightarrow A$, so 
$$\Rightarrow A\wedge (A\vee B)$$
And now we can use the law, that $A\wedge C \Rightarrow A$ for any $C$, in this case $C\equiv (A\vee B)$, so finally we have 
$$A\vee (A\wedge B) \Rightarrow A$$

Now the only thing we have to do is just mixing up these two implications and finally we obtain
$$A\vee (A\wedge B) \Leftrightarrow A$$

Comment: Well yes,but that's a proof using a truth table.Even when using this method,it can be clearly seen that these two proposition simplify to A.Is it possible to simplify the expressions just to A?

Comment: @Some1 You can look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a classic, where it is easy to go in circles indefinitely:

$A \lor (A \land B) = (A \lor A) \land (A \lor B) = A \land (A \lor B) = (A \land A) \lor (A \land B) = A \lor (A \land B) = ...$

How to break the cycle and just get to $A$, which we know these statements are all equivalent to?

Well, with $\top$ the symbol for a tautology (always true), we have:

$A \land \top = A$

and:

$A \lor \top = \top$

With those:

$A \lor (A \land B) = (A \land \top) \lor (A \land B) = A \land (\top \lor B) = A \land \top = A$